# Is there an "in memory" setting for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unit-testing, in-memory

I'm curious if SQL Server can allow for the creation of in memory databases.

Currently I'm looking at unit testing/integration testing some data layer code that is connected to SQL Server.

In the past I have availed myself of SQLite's support for this concept and found it invaluable.

Comment: 'Yes', it is called transactions :p

Comment: See the thread here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/sqldatabaseengine/thread/ff4c03ca-7d3d-47f5-8113-4a951c8bbd80

Comment: Thank you @DavidBrabant I actually saw this earlier.  I've scoured the net for information but am only finding market-speak and unrelated performance focused articles.

Comment: Make a database on a ram-disk? ramdrive.sys don't comes with current windows anymore, but there are many third party solutions in the web.

Comment: @leppie if the transaction or code failed, that memory operations will be flushed to disk :p

Answer (score 1):

You could mount either an SSD drive or a ramdisk on your server and then put a regular database on that volume?

Otherwise, no.

I've not mentioned Table Variables as they're only partly held in memory and are likely to be too transient for your requirements.

Comment: Bad idea. Lifetime of the SSD reduce rapidly like this. I guess you mean just add a good old RAM-DRIVE (in memory of good old ramdrive.sys :-))

Comment: You hear that about SSDs, but I'm not clear how much is repeated hearsay. RAM disk is the generic term for a chunk of memory imitating a disk volume.

Comment: This abstracts things at the wrong level unfortunately.  I want the SQL engine to be aware of being in memory so it can simply drop the DB from memory.  I'd prefer not to have to erase files from the filesystem, even if it is not a platter-based disk.

Comment: That's a shame, if I just change my answer to "No" will I get an accepted answer? ^_^